# Move to the next cell in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel VBA coding.
I have the address of the last non-blank cell in a row A1
And now I want to move to the next right cell.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell1 As String
Dim cell2 As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("ADS User Data")
Set rng1 = ws.Rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
MsgBox rng1
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "rng1 contains " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
    cell1 = (rng1.Address(0, 0))
    cell2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select()

     MsgBox cell1
     MsgBox cell2
Else
    MsgBox ws.Name & " row A1 is completely empty", vbCritical

End If
```

Output Cell Address: API1

Req Is: Move right to the output cell address (API1), that is the output is APJ1

Can anybody help me plz.

Comment: `cell2 = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Address(0,0)`

Comment: this is working fine. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is moving one cell **down** rather than one cell to the **right**:

Instead:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell1 As String
    Dim cell2 As String
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("ADS User Data")
    Set rng1 = ws.Rows(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)

    MsgBox rng1.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & rng1.Value

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

        cell1 = rng1.Address(0, 0)
        rng1.Offset(0, 1).Select
        cell2 = Selection.Address(0, 0)
        MsgBox cell1
        MsgBox cell2
    Else
        MsgBox ws.Name & " row A1 is completely empty", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]